# How can I extract information from a recordList returned as node in python using py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

My question is when I have my result as recordList and returned values are nodes then how can I extract information like properties of any particular node from recordList data structure?

```
results = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (n:Person) return n")
for index in range(len(results)):
        print results[index].n
```

Returned:

```
(n3:Person {birthday:"17/8/2001",name:"John",sex:"male"})
(n4:Person {birthday:"17/8/2001",name:"John",sex:"male"})
(n5:Person {birthday:"17/8/2001",name:"John",sex:"male"})
```

How can I extract name, sex properties out of returned recordList or Only way is to write cypher that return name and sex of all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

A node has `.properties`:

```
results = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 10")

for row in results:
    properties = row.n.properties
    print(properties['name'])
```